# FB.api('/me') always giving error code:2500 in phonegap android

Tags: android, facebook, phonegap-plugins

I am using facebook plugin to login and logout a user, which are working fine. The problem is when I request for the logged in user details using the function FB.api('/me'), it always gives the following error:

```
      {"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}
```

I used the debug mode to check PluginResult(pr) and JSONObject of the response. JSONObject contains the user information, which I required, I dont get where I am doing wrong.

```
  Plz help......
```

MY CODE:

```
           function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.session) {
                 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   console.log('Good to see you, ' + JSON.stringify(response) + '.');
                 });
               } else {
                 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
               }
             },{scope: 'email,user_likes'});
        }

       function logout() {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                           console.log(localStorage.getItem("user_fb_log_status"));
                           localStorage.setItem("user_fb_log_status","LOGGED_OUT");

                      alert('logged out');
                      });
        }

The above code is working fine to login and logout the user. Below is the code i used to get the user details,

        function me() {
                FB.api('/me', { fields: 'id, name, picture' },  function(response) {
                   if (response.error) {
                   alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                   } else {
                   var data = document.getElementById('data');
                   fdata=response.data;
                   console.log("fdata: "+fdata);
                   response.data.forEach(function(item) {
                                         var d = document.createElement('div');
                                         d.innerHTML = "<img src="+item.picture+"/>"+item.name;
                                         data.appendChild(d);
                                         });
                   }
                   });

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.api method is working fine for me to get the user details and post a feed to the facebook after I change the following method in ConnectPlugin.java as following.

```
  public JSONObject getResponse() {
    String response = "{" + "\"status\": \""
            + (facebook.isSessionValid() ? "connected" : "unknown") + "\","
            +
            // "\"session\": {" + "\"access_token\": \""
            // + facebook.getAccessToken() + "\"," + "\"expires\": \""
            // + facebook.getAccessExpires() + "\","
            // + "\"session_key\": true," + "\"sig\": \"...\","
            // + "\"uid\": \"" + this.userId + "\"" +

            "\"authResponse\": {" +

            "\"accessToken\": \"" + facebook.getAccessToken() + "\"," +

            "\"expiresIn\": \"" + facebook.getAccessExpires() + "\"," +

            "\"session_key\": true," +

            "\"sig\": \"...\"," +

            "\"userId\": \"" + this.userId + "\"" +

            "}" + "}";

    try {
        return new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new JSONObject();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need access token to retrieve more details than basic user information. Check that whether you have correct  access token in  [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to and ensure that you have all require permissions set [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Problem solved after changing the "session" in 'getResponse' method in ConnectPlugin to "authResponse"

Comment: Thanks for your response, I checked my access-token in DEBUG TOOL you mentioned it is giving me the correct details. But in my what ever I do it is giving the same error. Can you tell me from where the "FB.api" takes my access-token? I tried retrieving the user info immediately after login as given in this link but again the same error occurs.      http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Check Permissions on this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ . You need to define correct scope at scope: 'email,user_likes' . The same scope that you are defining at debug tool.

Comment: I did that too. I will post my code in the question. plz let me if I made any mistakes in that.

Comment: From where the FB.api method takes my access-token

Comment: You need to call FB.api inside fb.login function. See this thread for a similar implementation http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4758770/how-to-get-access-token-from-fb-login-method-in-javascript-sdk

Comment: Thank you so much @ gauravtechie. It worked after I change the "session" in 'getResponse' method in ConnectPlugin to "authResponse"

Comment: Pleasure. Updated my answer with correct solution. Please close that. Thanks.