# An Error Occur Please Try Again Later(phonegap facebook plugin-android)

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

every one..i have one issue while runing phonegap facebook plugin.i have Downloaded phonegap facebook sdk from GITHUB & i have followed steps given on project documentation.steps i have done is

1) i have created phonegap project with phonegap vesrsion 1.4.1

2) i downloaded facebook connect plugin for phonegap version 1.4.1 from GitHub

3) in assets www folder i have this files

assets->www->

- facebook_js_sdk.js
- pg-plugin-fb-connect.js
- phonegap-1.4.1.js
- index.html

4) i have put ConnectPlugin.java in my src folder under package name **"com.phonegap.facebook"**

5) i have put this `<plugin name="com.phonegap.facebook.Connect" value="com.phonegap.facebook.ConnectPlugin"/>` this under res->xml->plugin.xml file

6) under the libs folder i have this three files

- facebook_js_sdk.js
- facebook-js-patch(i have copied this patch files directly from GitHub project)
- phonegap.jar

7) and finally in my manifest file i have given this `<meta-data android:name="APP_ID" android:value="APP_SECRET" />`

so,i have followed all above mention steps by this when i am clicking on login button facebook login dialog popup but when i am givining user name password and than login i am getting this error all the time as shown in below image

[image]

and when i click on retry button page is redirected to facebook home page directly inplace of going back to my application....

another issue is that clicking on Me Button also doesn't work it shows such error

[image]

i am stuck on this issue..is it because of facebook plugin or i am going wrong some where?

if any one have faced it before than guide me on it
Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

i solved my issue regarding login status...i did not initialize my app_id in html file...
another thing need to remember is that we don't need to give `<meta-data android:name="APP_ID" android:value="APP_SECRET" />` in manifest file...

still having one query when i am clicking on me button it shows me error as u can see in above alert msg... how to fix that?

**EDIT(ALL QUERY SOLVED)**

me function also works fine now 
from **ConnectPlugin.java** class i changed function **getResponse()** to this below mention code

```
public JSONObject getResponse() {
String response = "{" + "\"status\": \""
        + (facebook.isSessionValid() ? "connected" : "unknown") + "\","
        +
        // "\"session\": {" + "\"access_token\": \""
        // + facebook.getAccessToken() + "\"," + "\"expires\": \""
        // + facebook.getAccessExpires() + "\","
        // + "\"session_key\": true," + "\"sig\": \"...\","
        // + "\"uid\": \"" + this.userId + "\"" +

        "\"authResponse\": {" +

        "\"accessToken\": \"" + facebook.getAccessToken() + "\"," +

        "\"expiresIn\": \"" + facebook.getAccessExpires() + "\"," +

        "\"session_key\": true," +

        "\"sig\": \"...\"," +

        "\"userId\": \"" + this.userId + "\"" +

        "}" + "}";

try {
    return new JSONObject(response);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return new JSONObject();
```

}

now i am able to fetch friend list also
For more infor regarding this u can check this ....[FB.api('/me') always giving error code:2500 in phonegap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026875/fb-api-me-always-giving-error-code2500-in-phonegap-android)

Thanks Every One

Comment: Have you set the right domain URL in your facebook application's settings?

Comment: yes...i checked it twice

Comment: The redirect_uri you used could be missing a trailing slash. Try adding that to the facebook app settings and your redirect_uri.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon please check my edited question...now i am able to login and can check login status there is one more query i am getting is i am not able to run that me button in right way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I did not initialize my app_id in html file...
another thing need to remember is that we don't need to give `<meta-data android:name="APP_ID" android:value="APP_SECRET" />` in manifest file...

I hope it helps