# How to get Friend's Birthdate List From Face Book API using phonegap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am using phonegap-facebook connect plugin from 
[GITHUB](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/) 
it's a nice guideline.i have followed that and i am able to  fetch friend name list when i login via facebook.and i am using [this html](http://pastie.org/4370171) code.every thing goes fine my query is i need to fetch friend's birthdate list now.i have tried lots of things but not able to get that,bcs i really not have understood facebook phonegap plugin very well.so any one can guide some steps how can i get birthdate list?,i have given permission of firend birthday [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cbirthday) and u can see i am passing this `FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'id, name, picture,birthday' },` in my html file..i am not getting any result in device or emulator,i am getting this alert [image],when i remove ,`birthday` from here `FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'id, name, picture,birthday' },` than it shows me list of friend's with black imges please help me

Thanks

Comment: it shows only friends name list not parsing the birthday date from json response from api graph. @Aamirkhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Thing Goes Fine i was just missing to put acess token in my preference:(:(

For one who want to have a guide that how to take birthdate list of friends from facebook using pohnegap...

**step1:**

Follow my question.[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698642/an-error-occur-please-try-again-laterphonegap-facebook-plugin-android) do not forget to see my edited portion also....if u follow that u will be able to login via facebook,& also will be able to get friend list....

**step2** well by following step1 u will be able to get friend list for which we don't need to get any permission from facebook,but for fetching friends birthdate list we need some permission...so for that follow my question[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754554/how-to-get-friends-birthdate-list-from-face-book-api-using-phonegap) means this question only......

follow each and every steps of step1 & step2 carefully,
after doing this u r on the go just open javaclass ConnectPlugin.java and just put ur acess token at this line

```
prefs.edit().putString("access_token","UR ACESS TOKEN GOES HERE").commit();
```

and that's it run your program....:):)
Thanks 
Aamir