# Post on facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

I use facebook api to connect my apk with facebook. I want to post some text on my wall but I get error. This is code my post class:

```
public class UiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        public void onPreExecute() {
            // On first execute
        }

        public Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

             Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
             try {
                    String response = facebook.request("me");
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", "This test message for wall post");
                    parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                    response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
                    Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                    if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
                       Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                    }
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            return null;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
             // Result
        }
    }
```

This is what I get in log:

```
got response: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: To post on facebook wall first you need to be logged in? Are you letting user to login if he's not and after that try to post?

Comment: Maby that this post [here][1] can help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10169588/928591

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        } else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```